# How to enable quick edits from file manager in PhpStorm after install

Tags: phpstorm, default-programs

This [post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/09/quick-edits-with-phpstorm-8/) shows how to use quick edits, but how to open it from the system file manager by default? When I do `open with` in the context dialogue and then open it with `phpstorm.exe`, my PC ignores it and just goes back to Adobe Edge Code.

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit and PhpStorm 8.0.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx

But all I had to do was go the file properties > open with > browse.

No registry hacks!

However, this doesn't open in quick edit mode, but somewhat works. I guess it's just the way it is after reading [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/09/quick-edits-with-phpstorm-8/#comment-1674751661)

I guess this should've been in SuperUser, but I thought it was something in PhpStorm that was the solution.